# Recursive in Ruby - Return method in itself

Tags: ruby, recursion

I want to return the method in itself

```
def self.open_folder(file)
  Dir.glob(file+"*") do |subfiles|
    if File.directory?(subfiles)
      open_folder(subfiles) ###Problem here
    end
    if File.file?(subfiles)
      open_file(subfiles)
    end
  end
end
```

What I want is to return the "open_folder" to keep open the sub-folder. I got an error

```
block in open_folder': stack level too deep
```

Can you help me to find the solution for it?

Comment: fix your indentation.

Comment: hmmm "stack level too deep" mostly means you have infinite recursion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works for me:

```
def open_file(file)
  # Do your stuff here
  puts file
end

def open_folder(file)
  Dir.glob("#{file}/*") do |subfile|
    File.directory?(subfile) ? open_folder(subfile) : open_file(subfile)
  end
end

open_folder('path/to/directory')
```

NOTES:

1. You don't need to define the methods as `self.*` if you are running this code directly in `irb` or outside any class defined by you.
2. I used string interpolation (`#{foo}`) instead of concatenating the string.
3. Appending a '*/**' to file path will look for all files and directories directly under the parent (not the nested subdirectories and files).
4. Instead of using 2 `if`s, you can use `elsif` in this case as only 1 of the condition can be true in each iteration.

Comment: you have a typo : `elsie` :)

Comment: thanks man.. it works like a charm. just #{file} fuq me up tho :D

Comment: Fixed typo. Thanks. :)

Comment: No need for `elsif`. If a path isn't a directory, it's a file.

Comment: If it's not clear, @EricDuminil is suggesting you change `elsif` to `else`. Being short, you could use a ternary operator: `File.directory?(subfile) ? open_folder(subfile) : File.file?(subfile)`.

Comment: Ok. i wasn't sure if there can be any other type of subfile. That's why used `elsif`. Will change it to `else` now.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to apply some method to every file in subdirectories, you could use :

```
Dir.glob("**/*").select{ |path| File.file?(path) }.each{ |file| open_file(file) }
```